# Group by weekdays and plot graph panda

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df1=df.groupby(['usertype','day']).size().reset_index(name='times')
```

[image]

how to plot bar graph by group day and user type.

Comment: Please provide your data as text, preferentially as code to directly create the dataframe. Also explain what you would like to achieve

Comment: Instead of the image of the data frame, a textual representation that can be copied is welcome.

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
>>> df.pivot(index="day", columns="usertype", values="times").reindex(days).plot.bar()
```

[image: Graph]